# How to make jQuery Mega Menu drop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking at the code from this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml

I would like to modify the code to make the menu drop up instead of drop down. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   var menuleft=($(window).width()-(megamenu.offsetx-$(document).scrollLeft())>megamenu.actualwidth)? megamenu.offsetx : megamenu.offsetx-megamenu.actualwidth+megamenu.anchorwidth //get x coord of menu

   var menutop=megamenu.offsety+megamenu.anchorheight  //get y coord of menu
```

These two lines (from `jkmegamenu.js`) assign values which are later used to position the menu when it is shown. `menutop` is the distance from the top edge of the window, `menuleft` the distance from the left edge. Playing with how these values are calculated will allow you to display the menu at any old coordinate you please :)

Good luck!

Comment: How do I change the values around?